# postgresql - data for 1st day of each month, or next day if no data for that day

Tags: postgresql

i need to get the balance for the 1st of each month from a table ordered by date, if the 1st is missing from the dataset for a certain month then for that month i want the next available dates data.
I have tried many things but I tried the following to place a case in the where statement which just gives me the first and the second any ideas, maybe an over statement

```
select date_
, balance
from mytable
where case when extract(day from date_) = 1 then  extract(day from date_) = 1 else (extract (day from date_) = 2 )end
group by date_
order by date_ desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function `row_number`:

```
select * from 
   ( 
    select * , row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('month',date_) order by date_ ) rn
   ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was trying to get too, I though it might be usnig this function but wasnt sure about how to implement it, legend, now o nto my next problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (EXTRACT (day FROM date_))
       date_, balance
FROM mytable
ORDER BY EXTRACT (day FROM date_), date_;
```

That will get the first date for each month.